# Cannot find Underground Jungle Temple

Tags: terraria

On my 1.2 Terraria Map I have been mining from left to right in my large underground jungle using my rocket launcher. Despite this, I have had no luck on finding the Underground Jungle Lihzahrd Temple. I have been searching the layer above where lava constantly spawns.

Have I simply spawned in a world without one or am I searching in the wrong place? I have also considered using the clentimator with Dark Blue ammo to provide light, should I do that?

Comment: Are you talking about [Lihzahrd](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lihzahrd)?

Comment: What William Jackson said; pyramids are an alltogether different beast from Lihzahrd, the Underground Jungle temple/dungeon.

Answer (score 4):

What you're talking about is the Jungle Temple, or Lihzahrd.  It is definitely in your world, so long as your version of Terraria is 1.2.  I found mine by accident pre-hardmode.  It actually took me longer to find the Beehive then it did for the temple.  And my temple was actually well above the lava level of the area.

For reference, the temple is going to be around 1/6th the full size of the jungle.  You'll find it eventually.  It is, indeed, a pyramid shape with the top of it containing the entrance and the bottom containing the Altar.

Your best bet would be to continue exploring the jungle pre-hardmode.  Keep to the larger areas and don't start digging sideways until you can't find a way through anymore.  Bombs also help with clearing the area and won't damage the temple if you find it, since temple blocks can only be harvested by the best hardmode picks.

Comment: Unrelated to this question but at least in my large world I had 3 Beehives (with 3 separate Queen Bee spawners).

Comment: Yeah...if that's true, I only found the one...and it was a bitch to find.  >.<

Answer (score 3):

**Spelunker Potions** are a decent way to help find the Temple. They make pots and chests glow, and the pots and chests in the Temple have a different look than the ones in the Jungle.

However, if you are just tired of looking and willing to go outside in-game methods, you might benefit from the [MoreTerra](http://moreterra.codeplex.com/) utility. This creates a visual map from a world file, allowing you to easily find points of interest.